# Variable values to pass from local computer to remote in Pssession

Tags: powershell, sendmail, powershell-3.0, remoting

I have a powershell script. Executing this will create a session with remote computer and execute some scriptblock inside remote computer. After that execution I need to send a mail.

So, I get the arguments required (like from, to, subject, body, smtp server, credentials) etc locally as shown below:

```
 $param = @{
SmtpServer = 'SMTPServer'
Port = 587
UseSsl = $true
Credential  = $crede
From = 'server@domain.in'
To = 'userv@domain.in'
Subject = 'Hi'
Body = "Hello"
}
```

$crede has value (username explicitly given, password reading from a text file).

And I call that param as shown below:

```
Send-MailMessage  $using:param

This is inside an Invoke-Command.
```

But when I run this program it asks me for the mail message details like from, to, smtp server etc.. Please note that these values are given on $param locally. I guess $param values are not being passed to the remote session.

Can someone please support me. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Send-MailMessage @using:param`?

Comment: Can't help without seeing what your Invoke-Command looks like.....

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen:Yes, but same result.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue.

```
$processName = myProcess.exe
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $anycomputer -Credential $credentials

# powershell syntax requires -Scriptblock and { on this line
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
  param([string] $processName)
  Get-Process -Name $processName 
} -Args $processName

Remove-PSSession $session
```

Comment: Have already tried this but doesnt seems to work. My scenario (as I already said) is:

Computer A executes script A and creates a session with computer B and in B, it executes a script. Now, I want to send something like a flag value back to computer A (by removing the session), if the script did with the execution successfully. Now I need computer A to invoke a script residing in its local machine.

What happens for me is the 3rd script is invoked at the second computer itself, though I have written remove-session on the code. 

Any help for this?

Answer (score 0):

$processName = myProcess.exe
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $anycomputer -Credential $credentials

Invoke-Command -Session $session {Get-Process -Name $using:processName}

Comment: If you need to pass a variable from the the local session to a nested script block, you need to declare the variable in the first script block.

You can declare the variable from the local session in the first script block by using $using:variable, then use it in the next scriptblock by using... $using:variable.

$using only goes one deep.